# MySQL dead-locking with UPDATE JOIN and INSERT SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, deadlock

We've run into a considerable number of dead-locks recently and they seem to be happening at this query:

```
  INSERT 
    INTO link_click (link_id, created_at, weight)
  SELECT :link_id, :created_at, lw.weight
    FROM link_weight lw
   WHERE lw.link_id = :link_id AND lw.start_at < :created_at
ORDER BY lw.start_at DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Where `link_id` and `created_at` are passed in as PDO parameters
This is part of a larger transaction.

The dead-locks only appear to occur when the following separate query is running on a cron every 30 minutes:

```
UPDATE owner o
  JOIN (
    SELECT l.owner_id, 
           SUM((lc.state = 1) * lc.weight) total_pending,
           SUM((lc.state = 2) * lc.weight) total_confirmed,
           SUM((lc.state = 3) * lc.weight) total_awaiting_processing,
           SUM((lc.state = 4) * lc.weight) total_processed,
           SUM((lc.state = 5) * lc.weight) total_invalid 
      FROM link_click lc 
      JOIN link l 
        ON l.id = lc.link_id 
     WHERE (:owner_id IS NULL OR l.owner_id = :owner_id)
       AND lc.state != 0
  GROUP BY l.owner_id
       ) raw
    ON raw.owner_id = o.id
   SET o.total_pending = raw.total_pending,
       o.total_confirmed = raw.total_confirmed,
       o.total_awaiting_processing= raw.total_awaiting_processing,
       o.total_processed= raw.total_processed,
       o.total_invalid = raw.total_invalid
```

Where `owner_id` is passed in. This is a one shot query not in a transaction but takes roughly 30s to complete.

I wasn't aware that INSERT SELECT or UPDATE JOIN would lock any rows beyond themselves and cause such a dead-lock.

I guess my question is whether separating out the SELECTs (I don't need a FOR UPDATE lock) from each query would help this situation?

Or is it more likely that the dead-lock is coming from the first query's transaction and the second query is just slowing down the database and that's making the dead-locks more frequent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these indexes:

```
link_weight:  (link_id, start_at, weight) -- in this order
link:         (owner_id, id)              -- in this order
link_click:   (state, owner_id)           -- in this order
owner:        (owner_id, total_processed) -- in either order
```

If `owner` has `PRIMARY KEY(owner_id)` then don't add the `owner` index above.

The goal is to speed up processing to minimize deadlocks.  Since deadlocks probably cannot be completely eliminated, be read to rerun transactions when they do occur.

If that does not suffice, break up the `UPDATE` into two steps:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE raw
      ( INDEX(owner_id, total_processed) )
AS
    SELECT ...;   -- from your existing code
UPDATE owner o
  JOIN raw 
    ON raw.owner_id = o.id
   SET o.total_pending = raw.total_pending,
       o.total_confirmed = raw.total_confirmed,
       o.total_awaiting_processing= raw.total_awaiting_processing,
       o.total_processed= raw.total_processed,
       o.total_invalid = raw.total_invalid;
```

If you need further help, please provide

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
EXPLAIN UPDATE ...
SHOW CREATE TABLE ...
```

Comment: Oops, had a typo in the `GROUP BY`, `link_click` doesn't have an `owner_id` just a `link_id` (hence the join to the table `link`). I'm guessing that would change your index suggestion for `link_click` to `(state, link_id)`.

Comment: Owner doesn't have an `owner_id`, just its PK `id`.. so that's all good.

Comment: Cool, thanks so much, I'll have a tinker and look at the `EXPLAIN`s to see if I can get there. Temp table is a great idea. I'll accept once I'm happy!

Comment: @arth  SELECT @@innodb_adaptive_hash_index  to determine if the option is ON.   If not,  SET GLOBAL innodb_adaptive_hash_index=1;  can turn it on dynamically.  You may find some relief with this enabled.  If so, add/change in your my.cnf-ini.   Check my profile for contact information, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Looks like that setting is on for our DB

Comment: TY TY! Adding the the covering index for `link_weight` saved about 50% of the time on the INSERT SELECT select. Adding another covering index `(state, owner_id, weight)` index for `link_click` saved about 80% on the UPDATE JOIN select. Since making this change I've had no deadlocks! Pretty sure all the indexes in MySQL InnoDB are tied to the PK so I didn't bother with the `link` one as I already have `owner_id` as an FK.

Comment: @Arth - Good!  (*) Deadlocks may still be possible, just much less frequent. (*) Correct; if `owner_id` is the PK, don't add `INDEX(owner_id, ...)`.

Comment: Yep, will keep an eye on the exception log! `id` is the PK and `owner_id` is an FK for the table `link`. I'm pretty sure adding (owner_id, id) is redundant, because with MySQL Innodb `INDEX (column)` is effectively `INDEX (column, PK)` unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @arth  SHOW INDEX FROM link_click;  and  SHOW INDEX FROM link_weight; would shed more light on the UPDATE query.

Comment: (And that's one reason I asked for `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

Comment: @RickJames We just kind of get used to asking for details and sometimes the request is fulfilled.  Not regularly.  Even when we give the exact table names included to simplify the process for the person with the question to provide the details we need.